# Copy one div element complety and paste this on a file with selenium on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

good night to all, im have a question, im starter with selenium, and i trying to made a bot. all its working fine now. but i having a problem with a table in a div that need made scrolling for work and show news results, (work with ajax). but i solve the problem editing the style and now i can saw all the content in the inspector of element if i copy the element directly from the browser. no i like to made the similar action on the selenium with python (copy the element complety) and paste the same on a file maked with python. i know how made the file and write on him. but i dont saw how i can copy the element with all the content complety with selenium, exists some command for made this?. sorry for my bad english if dont understand some thing tell me please. thanks.

```
browser.execute_script('''document.getElementById("bottom-area").style.height= "6700px"'''); 
browser.execute_script('''document.getElementById("bottom-area").style.marginTop= "0px"'''); 
data = browser.find_elements_by_id("bottom-area"); 
file = open("file.html","x"); 
file = open("file.html","w"); 
for i in data: 
file.write(i.text) 
file.close();
```

solved: the solution its use the next method for obtain the data:

```
>>> data2 = browser.find_element_by_id("bottom-area");
>>> ht = data2.get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

Comment: whats your code?

Comment: ready i update bro sorry.